# Assigning random value to JButton

Tags: java, arrays, swing, random, jbutton

I need to assign different number from 1 to 8 to JButton Array. But the elements of array has to be different.

```
Random random = new Random();
        JButton[] number = {jButton1,jButton2,jButton3,jButton4,jButton5,jButton6,jButton7,jButton8,jButton9};
    for(int i = 0; i<data.lentgh; i++)
    {
         number[i].setText(1+random.nextInt(9)+" ");
    }
```

With this code, the elements of array can be different and sometimes some of elements can be same. I searched the internet but I couldn't find.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `random()`

```
for(int i = 0; i<data.lentgh; i++) // I think data should be replaced by number
    {
         number[i].setText((i+1)+"");
    }
```

It is not necessary that random() will always generate different no. Most of the time you will get no. which is already generated.

Comment: This is my homework and it is a simple game. Everytime when  I click the "start" button, values of  9 buttons has to be different.  With your code, values will be always same. @AJ.

Comment: What do you mean by `values` ?

Comment: values of JButtons @AJ. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Ms.Sahin.. Plz explain  .. `values of JButton`.. is  `values` => text of `JButton` ?

Comment: My code is exactly doing same.. setting  text of each button with different value

Comment: @Ms.Sahin are you sure about `data.length` in your  `for` statemen ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use LinkedHashSet to store the random number and then later you can iterate over the set and set the text of the button.

```
        Random random = new Random();
        JButton[] number = { jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, jButton4, jButton5,
                jButton6, jButton7, jButton8, jButton9 };
        Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        while (set.size() != 9) {
            set.add(1+random.nextInt(9));
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer s : set) {
            number[i].setText(s + " ");
            panel.add(number[i]);
            i++;
        }
```